# Laravel 5.5.6 backpack:base:install

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I'm trying to install Backpack base using this comand: php artisan backpack:base:install

After few seconds I receive this error:

[image]

I tried to install backpack/generators manually but the problem is still the same.

Comment: I already edited the .env file and added my database info but the problem still occurs.

Comment: Try manually loging into the database with your credentials

Comment: Since you are using homestead you should run that command inside your homestead box otherwise the connection won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Backpack can only be installed on an working Laravel instance. And it looks like your Laravel installation can't connect to the database. This usually happens:

A) when you haven't properly setup the `.env` file with your DB credentials; **review your `.env` file;** keep in mind you might also need to specify a db socket; by default homestead apps work with this db configuration:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=your_database_name
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

B) when you're running the command outside your homestead box; **SSH into homestead first, then run the installation commands;**

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all of your ideas but it still didn't work still, thanks for the suggestions. Anyways I just created a new project in laravel 5.5 and it did actually worked.